# Help with a class method?

Tags: php, class

From the demo below you can probably see what I am trying to do, the construct method works but the test method does not work, gives error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Can someone show me how to make something like this work?

```
<?PHP
//user.class.php file
class User
{
    public $pic_url;

    function __construct($session)
    {
        if($session->get('auto_id') != ''){
            $this->pic_url = $session->get('pic_url');
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    function test($session)
    {
        return $this->pic_url = $session->get('pic_url');
    }
}

$user = new user($session);

//this works
echo $user->pic_url;

//this one does not work
echo $user->test();
?>
```

Comment: don't take this personally, but after 12345 questions about session+classes you should consider getting either some "hands-on" expert opinion, tutoring, or a few extra hours learning the ins and outs of PHP + OOP... again, just my humble advice

Comment: Why are you returning a value from a constructor?

Comment: @Yacoby: indeed - having a coffee mug in front of my screen made me miss that 8) +1

Comment: `$user->test()` - you're not passing the $session object here. Please explain what the method is supposed to do.

Comment: @jcinacio, your comment did not help at all, in afact that is exactly what I am doing by posting the quesions here, 2nd) this has NOTHING to do with sessions, this was a made up example code, you know "example) to learn and understand the concept and it just so happens that this example does not work and all I read and practice will not make this work the way I think it would so thanks for the "humble advice" but no thanks at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> //this one does not work echo
>   $user->test();

Calling a function here without an argument should throw a warning

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for test(), called in ....
```

and because you are trying to access a function of that object which don't pass in test() call its throwing a Fatal error as well.

Just pass the $session argument to test() as well.

**OR you can try ..**

```
class User
{
    public $pic_url;
    private $class_session;

 public function __construct($session)
 {
     $this->class_session = $session;
     ... other code
 }
 function test()
    {
        return $this->pic_url = $this->class_session->get('pic_url');
    }
}

$user = new user($session);
echo $user->pic_url;
echo $user->test();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not supplying the $session to the function.

Comment: He's right, but I thought I'd explain the error message a little more. It states that you are calling `get` on a "non-object" - hence, `$session` is a non-object. From this you can deduce that `$session` isn't being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
//user.class.php file
class User
{
    public $pic_url;

    public function __construct($session)
    {
        if($session->get('auto_id') != ''){
                $this->pic_url = $session->get('pic_url');
        } else {
                return false;
        }
    }

    public function test($session)
    {
        if($this->pic_url == $session->get('pic_url')) {
            return $this->pic_url;
        } else {
            return 'test failed';
        }
    }
}

$user = new User($session);

//this works
echo $user->pic_url;

//this one does not work
echo $user->test();
```